# Pulling from bitbucket to Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, git, bitbucket

I am using bitbucket git repository so I can work on my iMac and Macbook.
I have all my files on the bitbucket repository but when I pull to my Macbook and open the project I can't see all the files although the files are found in the finder.

Do you guys know how can I fix that?

Regards.

Comment: Did you clone the repository first? If the repo wasn't originally created on your Macbook, you need to clone from the remote first; then you subsequently pull to receive changes.

Comment: When I opened Xcode I was asked if I wanted to start a project from a repository. I had chosen yes. However, only some classes are presented although all the files are in a local folder

Comment: It sounds like the project file hasn't been committed into the repo so the files exist but you get an old copy of the project. Run `git status` on both working copies, what does it say?

Comment: sorry but how do I do that. The files can be seen on the bitbucket website and on my computer

Comment: Xcode only supports a small subset of the commands available in git via its UI. Open up terminal, `cd` to your project directory, then type `git status`.

Comment: it says command not found. I am trying this on my mac that I am trying to download the files from my repo.

Answer (score 0):

just follow the instructions on the bitbucket webpage. if you need to use command line git with Xcode use xcrun before any git comands in terminal.

e.g.

```
xcrun git init
xcrun git status
xcrun git add.
```